# Nuxeo : Document or collection located in more than one location

Tags: nuxeo

Is it possible to have "Document" or "Collection" located in more than one location into the base ? For example, can i have "Document" or "Collection" linked to more than one folder ? From what i understand it is not possible.

Comment: What is your Nuxeo version?
What is your exact need? Have something like a Linux soft link?

Comment: I evaluate last available version. I would like to have something like soft link

Answer (score 0):

What you look for is called a "Proxy". See [NXDOC/Repository+Concepts](https://doc.nuxeo.com/x/HoAO#RepositoryConcepts-Proxies).

> A proxy is very much like a symbolic link on an Unix-like OS: a proxy
>   points to a document and will look like a document from the user point
>   of view:
>
> The proxy will have the same metadata as the target document, The
>   proxy will hold the same files as the target documents (since file is
>   a special kind of metadata).
>
> A proxy can point to a live document or to a version (check in
>   archived version).
>
> Proxies are used to be able to see the same document from several
>   places without having to duplicate any data.
>
> (...)
>
> If a proxy can not hold metadata, it can hold security descriptors
>   (ACP/ACL). So a user may be able to see one proxy and not an other.